# Short story about a future archaeologist finding a gramophone record

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, time-travel

Years ago I read a story about an archaeologist - either alien or one incredibly far away in earth's future -  finding an old record of some description and speculating about it. 
They thought it to be a Roman artefact and eventually managed to play it. Its purpose was thought to be that of creating pictures in the mind, and, as the picture it created for them was of a trireme, this confirmed their dating of it. There was more subtlety to it than this but I am hoping this will spark something and someone can tell me author and title.

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! Take a look at this [guide](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) to help jog your memory and [edit] any more details. Also, take a look at our [tour] to get a better understanding of our site and earn your first [badge](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/badges)!

Comment: I'm sure I have read it, and also thought there would be a trope for it, alas this seems not to be the case

Comment: Gramophone and vinyl are sort of muitually exclusive.

Comment: @ths "A gramophone record (phonograph record in the US), commonly known as a vinyl record or simply vinyl or record, is an analog sound storage medium in the form of a flat polyvinyl chloride (previously shellac) disc with an inscribed, modulated spiral groove. The groove usually starts near the periphery and ends near the center of the disc." (Wikipedia) Long ago, "phonograph" was reserved for cylinder machines and "gramophone" for disc machines; nowadays the terms are synonymous.

Comment: in my opinion, gramophones use shellac records.

Comment: @ths Obviously you know more about it than I do. Are you an audiophile? Why wouldn't the same phonograph be able to play either vinyl or shellac records? Would you have to use a different needle, or what?

Comment: old gramophones used a very thick and heavy needle which would surely destroy a modern record. i don't know how well it would play it (once).

Comment: I think I remember reading this one.

Comment: For anyone researching this two blanks I have found 'Motel of the Mysteries' seems close but does not have a record in it (that I can see), there is also 'Expedition to Earth' but that is a canister of film.

Comment: Not the story, but an interesting tale of an engineer reverse-engineering a vinyl record as if he were an future archeologist: https://www.newscientist.com/blogs/shortsharpscience/2009/01/vinyl-archeologist-plays-recor.html

Comment: Can't remember what sort of record it was. Was searching using a variety of terms - yes, there's a difference between shellac & vinyl but I think the term gramophone (in our house anyway) came to mean anything played on a turntable regardless. 
I am 60 - old enough to remember both shellac & vinyl. Still own both, can play both on a particular record player.
Anyway, that is not the point. The story about the tendency of the human psyche to find pattern and to fit what it finds into that pattern. It is less about the type of material the record is made of.

Comment: I first thought of Gregory Benford's "Time Shards" but that was about recordings in ancient pottery, and doesn't mention a trireme.

Comment: Thanks to those who have replied so far. It is strange not to be able to find it at all. The record was very central to the story - it isn't any of the stories suggested so far, but many thanks for the ideas.